# Laravel routes are not working

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-artisan, php-5.6

I have this really weird issue where the routing process on Laravel seems to not work at all.. I get `NotFoundHttpException` every time I try to load another route except the default one(`/`)

These are my files:

routes.php

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/test', function () {
    return "WORKING?";
});
```

website apache config (`myquotes.conf` located in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my.qoutes
    ServerAlias www.my.quotes
    ServerAdmin admin@my.quotes
    DocumentRoot /var/www/myquotes/public/
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

hosts rule

```
127.0.0.1   my.quotes
```

And `php artisan route:list` returns this

```
+--------+----------+------+------+---------+------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI  | Name | Action  | Middleware |
+--------+----------+------+------+---------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /    |      | Closure |            |
|        | GET|HEAD | test |      | Closure |            |
+--------+----------+------+------+---------+------------+
```

So I don't really understand where the problem is. If I try to load `/test` I get the error, if I edit the `function` form `/`, nothing happens in the browser, the same view with `Laravel 5` on it is shown. I have some other websites in `/var/www`, are those the problem or influencing it? The routes from the other websites are not working either. What should I do?

EDIT: Tested in both Chromium and Firefox and the same
EDIT2: Okay.. After some more tweaking I found out that the problem was that I had 3 websites active under `sites-enabled` directory in `/etc/apache2` and the webserver was using the first one's configuration file and not the one form `myquotes`. The question now is how to have multiple sites running  on the same webserver?

Comment: Usually there is a default config file (000default.conf). Add all <VirtualHost *:80> from the different sites in this one file. Or make sure all loose files are included in apache.conf.

Answer (score 1):

To manage different sites on the same webserver, you will need to create different **VirtualHosts** to a different port or domain, for example, inside `sites-enabled` with a symlink to `sites-available`, you can have:

```
site1.conf
site2.conf
site3.conf
```

Each of them in a different port on the same webserver and they will be accessible. Make sure that the ports you're using are opened. You can add an alias to each of them to handle them differently.

See the documentation [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html)